# Does dojo have deep mixin like jQuery.extend?

Tags: dojo

I know jQuery has deep mixin such as

```
var options = $.extend(true,target,object1,object2)
```

,does dojo have?if have how to use?if not how can i get the same functionality?thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have "lang.mixin" (http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/_base/lang#mixin), but it's not truly equivalent.

The following thread has more info:
http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Deep-dojo-mixin-td3986157.html

And Ken Benjamin took the time to write this:

```
    mixinDeep: function(dest, source) { 
     //Recursively mix the properties of two objects 
     var empty = {}; 
     for (var name in source) { 
          if(!(name in dest) || (dest[name] !== source[name] && (!(name in empty) || empty[name] !== source[name]))){ 
               try { 
                    if ( source[name].constructor==Object ) { 
                         dest[name] = this.mixinDeep(dest[name], source[name]); 
                    } else { 
                         dest[name] = source[name]; 
                    }; 
               } catch(e) { 
                    // Property in destination object not set. Create it and set its value. 
                    dest[name] = source[name]; 
               }; 
          }; 
     } 
     return dest; 
}
```

However, it has some limitations with Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same issue and decided to create [Jake](https://github.com/smaye81/jake), which is just a small file porting over jQuery functions that Dojo doesn't offer.  So, now I can use this with my Dojo app (and in any other situation where I can't use jQuery).

Feel free to use it to drop in your project.

It currently supports:

- extend
- each
- offset